# Simple mod_rewrite in existing website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm doing a website (for portuguese speaking countries) that displays phrases one at a time.

I would like to have simpler non-dynamic addresses for the site to be SEO friendlier and easier to memorize to the user. So my problem is this, and thanks in advance for all the help possible:

```
nfrases.com/ -> completely random phrase (don't need changing this!)
nfrases.com/index.php?id_frase=2222 -> phrase with ID (wanted this to be nfrases.com/2222)
nfrases.com/tag.php?tag_nome=amor -> random phrase with tag_nome (want: nfrases.com/amor)
nfrases.com/tag.php?tag_nome=amor&id_frase=2222 -> specific phrase with tag=amor (want: nfrases.com/amor/2222)
```

I think this is a noob question about mod_rewrite but that's exactly what I am! :D Already made several tries with the few knowledge I have but either i got 404 pages either the parameters wouldn't be received by the $_GET['tag_nome'] or $_GET['id_frase'].

The actual htaccess I have is this but it isn't working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.nfrases.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.nfrases.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(.*) index.php?id_frase=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+) tag.php?tag_nome=$1&id_frase=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Can you guys help me?

Thanks again for everything! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rewrite rules work for me on a [RewriteRule tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/):

```
#removes trailing slash
#/vida/222/ becomes /vida/222
#/222/ becomes /222
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301]

#/222 silently rewrites to /index.php?id_frase=222
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id_frase=$1 [L]

#/vida silently rewrites to /index.php?tag_nome=vida
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?tag_nome=$1 [L]

#/vida/222 silently rewrites to /index.php?tag_nome-vida&id_frase=222
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ tag.php?tag_nome=$1&id_frase=$2 [L]
```

Comment: the first RewriteRule was a perfect fit! the second is problematic ... http://www.nfrases.com/vida/ --> give a 404 page and http://www.nfrases.com/vida/595 ---> doesn't pass the id_frase variable! This is so confusing!!

Comment: Also Levi ... didn't quite follow you with the trailing slash thing. What trailing slash are you talking about and what's the benefits of it?

Comment: @AfonsoGomes I updated my answer to handle `/vida` and I explained the trailing slash concept.

Comment: Yes ... I want everything without the trailing slash... it's easier I guess. Also I think there's a bug on your rule suggestion as I want tag.php?nome_tag=vida to generate the address nfrases.com/vida but still ... the php doesn't collect the $_GET variables ... should I use a address snippet instead ? The $_GET not working confuses me

Comment: @afonsoGomes I have edited my code above to give a working solution.

Comment: Hey Levi! I appreciate all the help you're giving and the code you provided worked great on creating the URLs. However as the $_GET variables are not being passed correctly I did some tests. I used $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']  and it tells me that for the address nfrases.com/vida the $_GET variable is tag_nome=index.php instead of tag_nome=vida ... any idea how this is hapening?

Comment: Even more, shouldn't this rule RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?tag_nome=$1 [L] be RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ tag.php?tag_nome=$1 [L] ? I feel lost here :( don't know what the problem is... but i noticed if I comment the last 2 rules the 1st one works just fine.

Comment: @AfonsoGomes I noticed that you accepted the answer.  I think maybe the problem is that the second to last rule would overwrite the previous rule.   Try what I have posted now.

Comment: I already had accepted the answer cause the answer was what I needed and was only needing to clear some details that I was fully confident you wouldn't leave me without the perfect answer. Well ... I was right and everything now is working like a swiss clock! Thanks a lot for all your time! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In this case, nfrases.com/2222 will rewrited as index.php/2222. This easily allows base routing in your index.php file. For more advanced routing, it may be faster and easier to use a good framework. Take a look at FuelPHP (http:www.fuelphp.com) or CodeIgniter (http://www.codeigniter.com).

Comment: People might hate me for this, but I would not recommend CodeIgniter to anyone.  It's found a lot of use, but there are much better frameworks.  His site sounds pretty simple, I wouldn't want to use a full-featured framework on it anyway.

Comment: Sure, there are better frameworks. But CodeIgniter is the most watched PHP Framework at GitHub for several reasons. I have been using FuelPHP, but would recommend CodeIgniter over any other framework to a PHP newbie. And sure, he could write a router himself, but how long would it take? Any newbie with the phrases already in the database could write that application in CodeIgniter or FuelPHP in a few hours (considering the time to read the docs). For the code, no more than 10 minutes...

Comment: Will take a look at those. But I'm a noob when it comes to more complex systems and what I'm trying to achieve with this site is a simple, small, fast loading site. But thanks for the tip appreciate it!